# How can I change the selected alias in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am building a site with Drupal 7 in which I use the Domain Access ( http://drupal.org/project/domain) module, in combination with the Domain Path ( http://drupal.org/project/domain_path) module. I can set aliases for specific domains, and they work if I browse to example.com/alias, but the domain specific aliases do not show up in the menus. Only an alias set through the "URL path settings" in the node creation form shows up in menus. But I want to have different nodes with the same alias at the different domains.

So my question is how I can change the alias selection for nodes. Drupals default behavior is to select an alias for a node from the url_alias database table, but the Domain Path module stores the aliases in a different table.